# what is the definition of '$_product->unsFinalPrice()'?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

**Magento: what is the definition of '$_product->unsFinalPrice()' ? Please explain me.**

My issue is When I'm update the product price in admin panel, Price not getting updated in product listing page. But details page was fine.
If I load the product `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())` was fine, But I don't want to load the product each time.

Comment: You need redindex from index management from admin

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `$_product->unsFinalPrice()` is to `unset FinalPrice` on product object.

This are magic methods that magento implements like this:

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
        case 'get' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $data = $this->getData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $data;

        case 'set' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->setData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $result;

        case 'uns' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->unsetData($key);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $result;

        case 'has' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return isset($this->_data[$key]);
    }
    throw new Varien_Exception("Invalid method ".get_class($this)."::".$method."(".print_r($args,1).")");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `re indexing  from index management`(basically  Product Prices) from admin.That will resolved the issue in listing page.it magento basic.

If Catalog price rules then it may be affect on listing page price.You need to check that.